# Purpose of __init__

Tags: python, init

I've done some reading and can't grasp this as fully as I'd like to. I'm making a little "choose your own adventure" game from the LPTHW tutorial, here's the full script: http://codepad.org/YWVUlHnU

What I don't understand is the following:

```
class Game(object):

    def __init__(self, start):
        self.quips = [
            "You died. Please try again.",
            "You lost, better luck next time.",
            "Things didn't work out well. You'll need to start over."
            "You might need to improve your skills. Try again." 
        ]
        self.start = start
```

I get that we're creating a class, but why define `__init__`? Later on I do stuff like `print self.quis[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)]` which prints one of the four strings in `quips`, but why wouldn't I just create a function called `quips` or something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you call `Game("central_corridor")`, a new object is created and the `Game.__init__()` method is called with that new object as the first argument (`self`) and `"central_corridor"` as the second argument. Since you wrote `a_game = Game(...)`, you have assigned `a_game` to refer to that new object.

This graphic may make the process easier to understand:

[image: Python object creation]

*Note: The `__new__` method is provided by Python. It creates a new object of the class given as the first argument. The built-in `__new__` method doesn't do anything with the remaining arguments. If you need to, you can override the `__new__` method and utilize the other arguments.*

The practical reason `__init__()` exists in your program is set the `start` attribute on the `Game` instance you create (the one you call `a_game`), so that the first call to `a_game.play()` starts in the location where you want it to.

You're right about `quips`. There is no reason to have `quips` be set up in `__init__()`. You can just make it a class attribute:

```
class Game(object):
    quips = ["You died. Please try again.",
            "You lost, better luck next time.",
            "Things didn't work out well. You'll need to start over."
            "You might need to improve your skills. Try again." ]
    def __init__(self, start):
        self.start = start
```

Comment: I thought if I created an instance of the class `Game`, whatever attribute I use will determine where the game starts. So if I want the game to start by going to the `laser_weapon_armory` function in the class `Game`, I'd do `a_game = game("laser_weapon_armory")` then `a_game.play()`. What does `__init__` have to do with this?

Comment: The __init__ method sets up the base state of your object ... imagine if it needed to connect to a database and download some data first to prepare itself, you'd do that in the __init__ before doing other things.  It's like going to buy a car from a dealer ... without the __init__ you'd get a car object with no wheels, no engine, but you could still car.drive() it if you wanted to.

Comment: @ZCJ When you write `Game("laser_weapon_armory")`, what actually happens is a new `Game` instance is created, let's call it `obj` (it really has no name at this point), and then Python _automatically_ runs `Game.__init__(obj, "laser_weapon_armory")` and returns `obj` (which you end up assigning to the name `a_game`). `obj.start` is set to `"laser_weapon_armory"` by `__init__`. When you run `a_game.play()`, what's actually happening is Python is running `Game.play(a_game)` - the `self` argument is filled in with `a_game`, so `self.start` is `"laser_weapon_armory"` when you call `a_game.play()`.

Comment: @Series8217: Very nice answer - just being picky, `__new__` method is passed the same arguments that are later passed to `__init__` not just the class.

Comment: @jsbueno You are correct of course. I'll add a note about it.

Answer (score 5):

More broadly `__init__` and the lesser known and often more dangerous `__new__` methods of a python class are there to do the job of initializing the state of your object.

For your particular object it's not truly necessary and I suppose there are quite a few very simple data storage classes you could think of as not being needed to be initialized, but the reality of deeper programming with python is that virtually every more complex class needs to be initialized to its base state.

Additionally the big reason is to make your class multipurpose:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, word_of_power="Ni"):
        self.fact = "We are the knights who say %!" % word_of_power

>>> f = Foo()
>>> w = Foo("No!")
>>> print f.fact
"We are the knights who say Ni!"
>>> print w.fact
"We are the knights who say No!"
```

Comment: By "multipurpose", you mean I can use this class to create instances like `Foo()` as well as instances with an attribute like `Foo("No!")`? And you're saying that the benefit of making it multipurpose is so that these both will work?

Comment: @ZCJ, just to keep terminology straight, note that in the statement `Foo("No!")`, `"No!"` is _not_ an "attribute." It's an _argument_, and it works the same as the argument to any function. In fact, it can be helpful to think of `Foo` as a special kind of function that takes some number of arguments and returns an object of type `Foo`. `self.fact`, on the other hand, _is_ an attribute.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for the clarification- hammering down the terminology is something I'm trying to work on.  So `w.fact` in your response is an attribute, but when assigning variables `f` and `w` to different instances of `foo`, `foo` can take an argument within the parenthesis since the class allows it. Sound right?

Answer (score 1):

`__init__` works as constructor here. So when the game instance is created, the `__init__` method is called. If you define another method to set up *quips*, you'll have to call it explicitly.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `__new__` is the constructor and `__init__` is the "initializator".